# There was a general payment processing error. (result code = -12)

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I have web site developed in asp.net using Paypal  payflow pro Payment gateway When i am entering the test credit card  no on test website i  am getting this error .Please let me know how to resolve this......Error..**"There was a general payment processing error. (result code = -12)"**

Comment: Check in the documentation of Payal payflow what does resultcode, -12 means.

Answer (score 1):

For result code 12, paypal says:

```
Declined. Check the credit card number, expiration date, and transaction information to
 make sure they were entered correctly. If this does not resolve the problem, have the
 customer call their card issuing bank to resolve.
```

I hope you can get idea that why is it happening.

Comment: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/424/kw/result%20code%2012%20error.....